# how to change letters in a list to their corresponding alpabetical numbers in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to change letters in a list in python to their corresponding alphabetical numbers for a project in class. I have tried all the ways I know how and I still cant get it right. if someone can answer this question it would greatly help me in this, thanks

```
def main():
miriam = True
def letters():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = 5
    f = 6
    g = 7
    h = 8
    i = 9
    j = 10
    k = 11
    l = 12
    m = 13
    n = 14
    o = 15
    p = 16
    q = 17
    r = 18
    s = 19
    t = 20
    u = 21
    v = 22
    w = 23
    x = 24
    y = 25
    z = 26
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 4
    E = 5
    F = 6
    G = 7
    H = 8
    I = 9
    J = 10
    K = 11
    L = 12
    M = 13
    N = 14
    O = 15
    P = 16
    Q = 17
    R = 18
    S = 19
    T = 20
    U = 21
    V = 22
    W = 23
    X = 24
    Y = 25
    Z = 26
while miriam == True:
    codeDeCode = input("would you like to code or decode? ")
    if codeDeCode == "code":
        code = input("enter the text you would like to code")
        listedCode = list(code)
        listedCodeAmount = len(listedCode)
        print(listedCodeAmount)
        for x in range(0, listedCodeAmount):
            listedCode[x] = letters()

        print(listedCode)
```

the result I get out of this is

```
>>> main()
would you like to code or decode? code
enter the text you would like to codemiriam
6
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
would you like to code or decode?
```

I would like to get a result like this

```
[13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13]
```

I would really appreciate someone's help on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in range(0, listedCodeAmount):
    listedCode[x] = letters()
```

This is not how functions work. Your function doesn't have a return value so it returns `None`. You are trying to treat that function as if it's a list or other container. You are just setting a bunch of variables in the functions scope and then dropping them on the floor when it's done.

```
import string


miriam = True

def get_letter_dict():
    return {val: idx for idx, val in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}

while miriam == True:
    letter_dict = letters()
    code_decode = input("would you like to code or decode? ")
    if code_decode.lower() == "code":
        code = input("enter the text you would like to code:\n")  # makes it easier to read
        listed_code= [letters[c] for c in code.lower()]
        print(listed_code)
```

So the first thing we did was import the `string` module this will help us make our dictionary. Then we set your variable as `True` so you can exit the program later.

Next, we made a function to get our dictionary. You could do this by hand of course but this is much easier. I used a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Notice how I used `return` (learn more about it [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html)) in the function. This makes it so I can save the results of the function to a variable. Notice I used `string.ascii_lowercase` to build the dictionary. This is a string that contains all lower case letters form a-z. Case is important when using keys or comparing strings. Remember `'m' != 'M'`. You can read about what enumerate does [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Some of the following code should look familiar so I won't go in to any detail. However I did change how you built your list. I used a list comprehension which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

I also changed the name of your variables to the suggested Python naming conventions. Variables are named `likeThis` in other languages, in Python we name variables `like_this` instead. It's much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [29]: mydict=dict(zip(string.letters,[ord(c)%32 for c in string.letters]))

In [30]: code="miriam"

In [31]: li=list(code)

In [32]: [mydict[i] for i in li]
Out[32]: [13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13]
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of @stephanpochmann's answer including his different capitalization of the word 'Miriam'.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import string
```

Build a dictionary mapping from letters to numbers:

```
codes_letter_to_number = {letter: i for i, letter in 
                          enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
```

and the other way:

```
codes_number_to_letter = {v: k for k, v in codes_letter_to_number.items()}
```

code:

```
[codes_letter_to_number[letter.lower()] for letter in 'miriam']
```

gives:

```
[13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13]
```

decode:

```
''.join(codes_number_to_letter[i] for i in [13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13])
```

gives:

```
'miriam'
```

Now, put all in nice functions:

```
import string

LETTER_TO_NUMBER = {letter: i for i, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
NUMBER_TO_LETTER = {v: k for k, v in LETTER_TO_NUMBER.items()}

def code(word):
    return [LETTER_TO_NUMBER[letter.lower()] for letter in word]

def decode(number_list):
    return ''.join(NUMBER_TO_LETTER[i] for i in number_list)
```

Now:

```
code('miriam')
```

returns:

```
[13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13]
```

and

```
decode([13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13])
```

gives:

```
'miriam'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary:

```
My_Dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} # you can fill in the rest
My_Message = "abba"
My_Numbers = []

for letter in My_Message:
    My_Numbers.append(My_Dictionary[letter])
print My_Numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [ord(c)-64 for c in 'MiRiaM'.upper()]
[13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13]
```

If you're wondering about the 64... that's because `ord('A')` is 65. If you want to be clearer, you could do this:

```
>>> [ord(c)-ord('A')+1 for c in 'MiRiaM'.upper()]
[13, 9, 18, 9, 1, 13]
```